# Condition formatting based on TRUE/FALSE output of another cell

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, conditional-formatting

I have 2 tables:

1. containing values
2. containing TRUE/FALSE outputs based on a formula that depends on the values of Table 1

I would like to apply condition formatting so that Table 1 cells are color RED with corresponding FALSE outputs from Table 2.

Comment: Conditional Formatting should do it. What have you tried?

Comment: Yes I have with making my own rule but it didn't work for the whole table. I had to do it in separate sections.

Comment: that doesn't really help us here. Can you please post what you've tried, what works and what doesn't?

Comment: @Emma, could you share sample data along with Formula you have used for TRUE/FALSE, help us to fix it in better way!

Comment: For which app is this?

Answer (score 2):

For example, this is your data:

```
      A      B
1     3    FALSE
2     2    TRUE
3     7    FALSE
4     9    TRUE
```

So now you want to format the text color of cell A1 and A3 to be red.

So these steps that I have tried:

1. Put your cursor at **A1**
2. In **Home** tab, choose **Conditional Formatting**, then **New Rule...**
3. In **New Formatting Rule** choose **Use a formula to determine which cell to format**.
4. Write this formula in **Format values where this formula is true** : `=B1=FALSE`, then set the formatting as you want by clicking **Format...** button. Then click OK.
5. Now open again **Conditional Formatting**, then choose **Manage Rules...**
6. Then in **Applies to** change this `=$A$1` to `=$A$1:$A$4`. Click button `Apply` then OK.
7. Now you can see text color in cell **A1** and **A3** are red.

Hope it is useful.

Comment: You can skip steps 5 and 6 if, at step 1, you just select `A1:A4`.

Answer (score 1):

*Your issue can be fixed using helper Column.*

[image]
**N.B.**

- Since you have not provided any sample data so that I've assumed two set of data for Tables.

**How it works:**

- I'm assuming *Table 1* has data in Range 
  `A2:B4` and *Table 2* has `D2:E6`.
- Enter this Formula in `F2` and fill it down.

  `=AND(COUNTIF(B$2:B$4,E2)>0,D2>IFERROR(OFFSET(B$2,MATCH(E2,B$2:B$4,0)-1,-1),0))`
- Select `B2:B4`, reach to **Conditional 
  Formatting** then **New Rule**  and enter this 
  Formula `=$F2 =FALSE`.
- Apply an appropriate **Format** & finish with 
  **Ok**.

**Let me say that how the formula works:**

- The `COUNTIF()... > 0` part returns `TRUE` if 
  the value in Column `E` occurs in  `B2:B4`.
- In second part the `MATCH()` finds the position 
  of the the data in  Column `E` Match with `B2:B4`.
- The `OFFFSET()` finds the corresponding data 
  in Column `A`.
- `IFERROR()` handles `#N/A` error.
- If `D2` is not greater than the Data (Number) 
  in  Column `A`, Formula returns `FALSE`.

*Adjust Cell references in the Formula as needed.*